# find any last character in line except empty lines

Tags: regex, ssms

I need to find any last character in line and then add extra text (for example "word"), but without applying this rule to empty lines (no characters in line).

My expression like `([^\n])$` works for empty lines, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(\S[^\S\n]*)
```

Replace with `$1 word`. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/vMmEXv/3).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\S\n]*                 any character except: non-whitespace
                             (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), '\n'
                             (newline) (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: almost works but in my find&replace Microsoft SQL server's menu it still applying to empty lines

Comment: Empty or blank? Try `([^ \t][ \t]*)$`. Try `(\S[^\S\n]*)$`, too.

Comment: ... yes, blank... like paragraph (Pilcrow) blank space